# .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/configatron-2.9.1/lib/configatron/store.rb:328:in `<class:Store>': uninitialized constant Psych::Syck (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, padrino

I am getting error while I am doing padrino start.

I uninstalled and installed many times gems, rvm and ruby even bundler and then installed , but every time getting error **uninitialized constant Psych::Syck (NameError)**

```
bharath@bharath-HP-ProBook-6450b:~/workspace/consumer_api$ padrino start
```

> /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/configatron-2.9.1/lib/configatron/store.rb:328:in
>   `': uninitialized constant Psych::Syck (NameError)
>
> from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/configatron-2.9.1/lib/configatron/store.rb:2:in `<class:Configatron>'<br/>
>     from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/configatron-2.9.1/lib/configatron/store.rb:1:in`' 
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/configatron-2.9.1/lib/configatron.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' <br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`require'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`each'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`each'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require' <br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in`require'
>       from /home/bharath/workspace/consumer_api/config/boot.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/padrino-core-0.10.7/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:23:in`require'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/padrino-core-0.10.7/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:23:in `start'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in`run'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor.rb:275:in`dispatch'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/padrino-core-0.10.7/bin/padrino:9:in`'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/padrino:23:in `load'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/padrino:23:in`'
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'<br/>
>       from /home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'

Comment: can you paste your database.yml file? or any other yml file you are using in application

Comment: @PravinMishra , I can't paste my database.yml file.Due to some restriction , Can you please tell me what would wrong in that file so that I can check. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I used to face this issues most of time due to wrong indentation in YML file. Once have a close look.

Comment: I solved the problem using appropriate RVM-ruby version. For my application ruby-1.9.3.p194 was needed. For now My padrino start is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using appropriate RVM-ruby version. For my application ruby-1.9.3.p194 was needed. For now My padrino start is working fine.